# Edit for iframe contents

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

Is there anyway I can edit the html content of an iframe inside a webpage?

I have the following code:

```
<iframe src="sample.html"></iframe>
```

I want to edit the contents of *sample.html* without literally touching the html code. And I want this editor to be embedded on the website. Thank you so much!

Comment: note: please use the code formatting when posting questions and answers.

Comment: Does sample.html exist in the same domain? (on the same server/path of the *editor*?

Comment: <iframe src="sample.html"></iframe>

Comment: I want the editor to exist in the same domain

Comment: Iframes are so outdated solutions. Tell us your higher goal and we will find you a better way.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the document of the `<iframe>` like so:

```
iframedoc = document.getElementById("my_iframe").contentDocument;
iframedoc.getElementById("element_in_iframe").do_something();
```

Note that this only works if the iframe is on the same domain as your parent page.