# How to Edit content inside an Iframe or add styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `<iframe>` tag.

I don't know how to add content to that `<iframe>`

example:---

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://musafiroon.github.io/stackoverflow/index.html" width="200"/>
```

at https://musafiroon.github.io/stackoverflow I have made 3 elements with attribute `class="text"`

**I want to color all these text blue in my Iframe.**

how should I do this?

*I am working on my pc with some HTML files inside a folder*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe) or [Edit for iframe contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834014/edit-for-iframe-contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the iframe `src` url belong to the same origin as the main page? Are they accessed by the same domain name?

#### If the main page and the iframe content share an origin

[Javascript and same origin iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689984/javascript-and-same-origin-iframes)

#### Otherwise

You'll need to change something so they share an origin. You can put the iframe content behind a proxy so it shares the main page's origin. If your main page is a dynamic site, you can add a new endpoint (e.g. `/iframe`), and in the request handler (on the server side) you request your iframe content and return it. Alternatively, you can use a CDN service like AWS CloudFront or Akamai to combine the main page and the iframe content domains into a single domain. You would configure it so that requests to `/iframe/*` are served by `your-iframe-content.com/*`, and all other requests are served by your main content server. [Explanation for CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/)

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can change color of the content in the iframe by defining color of the class--text in the source file "index.html".
You can set the color of the content in iframe as per below code..

```
<style>
.text{
    color:blue;
}
</style>
```

with your main code.

Comment: He doesn't want to touch `index.html` file of  the iframe source

Answer (score -1):

You can't edit the content of an `iframe` tag.

Comment: how can I do It?

Comment: please give an example.

Comment: you just cant, its like a hole in your website, you can only set the height & width that it takes, maybe border